# How can I access controller methods via url in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'n new to Laravel and I'm not quite sure of all the routing stuff yet, so I want to do things the way I'm comfortable with for the time, which is accessing a controller method via url.  So I have a controller called User, in that a function called getLogin().  I want to access this via 'mydomain.com/user/login'.  It doesn't currently work, so how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel does not automatically map routes in `controller/method` fashion.

You have not posted what is in your routes.php file, but one of the simplest approaches is to do this:

```
Route::get('users/login', array('as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'User@getLogin'));
```

There are multiple approaches, though. You might consider reading the docs about [routing](http://four.laravel.com/docs/routing)

Comment: Hmm ok, so I need to forget the familiar controller/method approach Mvc approach :(.  Ok..I shall endeavour to use routes then...

Comment: Yeah, Phil Sturgeon wrote an article on his blog about this. His last paragraph actually makes a point, even if you generally hate the idea of manually mapping the urls to actions. http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2013/07/beware-the-route-to-evil . So at least your project will get better documented :)

Comment: yes I do see the advantage now, everything the app can possibly do will be in one file...just a case of getting used to it

Answer (score 3):

While I agree with Phil Sturgeon's article that for a typical app, it's wise to make routes as obvious as possible, there are some cases where a url segment to controller method scheme might be convenient. I sometimes use Laravel for prototyping/testing some code and need a predictable url-to-method to spin off examples. You can grab the segment using Request::segment() and camelcase it using Laravel's [Str::camel()](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Support.Str.html). For example,  with a route like:

```php
Route::get('/lara-learn/{method}',
    array(
        'as' => 'lara-learn_' . Request::segment(2),
        'uses' =>  'LaraLearnController@' . Str::camel( Request::segment(2) )
       )
);
```

You can visit `/lara-learn/lara-config` and land on the laraConfig() method:

```php
class LaraLearnController extends BaseController {

    public function laraConfig(){
        return "hey from laraConfig";
    }

}
```

If we want, we can also choose the controller dynamically from the url, say using the first segment. So we can generalize our route even more:

```php
Route::get('/{controller}/{method}',
    array(
        'as' => Request::segment(1) . '_' . Request::segment(2),
        'uses' =>  studly_case( Request::segment(1) ) . 'Controller@' . Str::camel( Request::segment(2) )
       )
);
```

Visiting `/lara-learn/lara-config` should land us on the laraConfig method example above.

Answer (score 0):

Route::resource('/recipes', 'recipesController@index');

you have to make route like this and u have to access it in url as

localhost/projectname/public/recipes